# Is there a way to verify an original author using encryption?

Tags: signature, verifiability

I feel like the title explains the problem fairly well. Is is possible to use encryption to verify a document's original author? In my case, I have a doc that I want to release online. Is there a way I can make sure that anyone who finds the doc can verify that I was the original author who created it and not someone who just copied it?

Comment: If the format supports it, you could digitally sign it with a certificate that proves your identity and get it time stamp authority signed, so no one can claim a copy older than yours.

Comment: If its a novel it would be pretty normal to strike your best "the fonz" pose and include that picture in the cover. This means now all you need is a hash of the document stored somewhere publicly that is older than your release date to show your face was in the author box of the document.

Comment: @bartonjs I will probably use this method, as long as the time stamp authority doesn't close up shop at some point in the future. Is there a method of verification if the authority goes offline?

Answer (score 1):

Yesish, but only for cryptographic purposes within the scope of this forum.  My last bit will show that this isn't worth hill of beans legally, which also makes this question entirely off topic for practical purposes.

You could do this with a time stamping authority:-

[image: not ip proof]

All good fun for amateur cryptographers, but the problems start at step 1. A hash is performed of your original document.  Any good cryptographic hash (such as SHA-256) produces effectively unique outputs for any given input.  Even if the inputs only vary by one bit. So

H("Tankobot") ≠ H("Tankobot ")

There's an extra space at the end of the second hash.  The little bits of the two hash outputs will be approximately 50% different. This is due to the avalanche effect inherent in all respectable hashes.

The negative consequence of this is that your plagiarised work will have to be word for word, character for character and bit for bit the same as your original.  It will have to be in the same human language and the same computer character set.  You'll have to retype and re format the suspect work to then perform the validity check to prove ownership. The slightest variation will result in different signed hashes.

That's great for ASCII type text. If your document is graphical, there are sophisticated [water marking](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/68b3/223df4392cbad7863fff582437ff36b20cb2.pdf) techniques which are allegedly robust but have not really be field tested. Results for this are below, but I'm not sure how well noise robustness helps if the student redraws your document images:-

[image: robustness]

That's all wonderful and this answer stops here wrt cryptography.  In the real world, you're wasting your time.  You might as well post the document to yourself and pray. It might work if you catch a student cheating with homework and spank them.

In court, it's worthless.  This type of effort is termed *Poor Man's Copyright*.  Neither the courts or copyright offices of the UK nor US recognise these *clever* techniques.  The time stamp has zero evidentiary value in copyright terms.  Independent creation, derivative works and eye witness testimony of copying are some of the easy spanners that smash your system. This is an immense sector of law and I'm not qualified to provide advice. You'd better not be spanking any students as they can sue you if you can't prove they cheated in court.

Comment: This *answer* is almost entirely off topic. My question does not concern whether any method will hold weight in court. I only want to know if someone who acquired the document (no changes being made) could reliably verify that the document was originally authored by a particular person (or holder of an asymmetric key if that was required).

Comment: This answer is also pretty gloomy, timestamps must have some uses worth legal weight, alibi files maybe, internet... trade ... computers. The classic use is proving an original idea not a word for word document.

Comment: At best, a cryptographic timestamp could prove that your work is earlier than another work where the purported author of the other work admits a creation date later than your timestamp. Cryptography can't prove you didn't transcribe the work from a paper notebook you found.

Comment: @Tankobot First 2/3rds of my answer deals with the mathematical issues. That'd be the bit showing the flow chart of how to actually do it.  The legal stuff's at the end below the bit that says "and this answer stops here wrt cryptography."

Comment: @daniel Sorry but I'm a depressive by nature.  Check with your IP office.  Your ideas are worthless in **copyright** law as you can't copyright or patent an idea.  Time stamps have merit in other branches of law, but **not** copyright.  All that a time stamp (possibly) proves is the existence of something, **not** the authorship.  There's mountains of legal opinion confirming this.

Comment: @Tankobot Isn't it also rather naive to develop a cryptographic solution to something that's not legal at all, therefore worthless? Just sayin'.